# How to "skip" a character in a string in Python?

Tags: python

I just stated learning Python. My teacher asked me to take this string `"quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog!"`, iterate all letter using `i in range()` function, and whenever I find a whitespace in the string I need to make the next character uppercase. So that the final output would be `Quick Brown Fox, Jumps Over The Lazy Dog!`

The teacher said that I may need to use `len(mastering)-1` for this homework.

Below is my code. I don’t know why I see the uppercase letter and then the repeated lower case of the same letter. I don't know how to skip them from the string during looping. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

I tried using different sequences in the for loop function but none worked.

```
mystring = 'quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog!'
newstring = mystring[0].upper()
for i in range (1,len(mystring)):
    newstring = newstring + mystring [i]
    if mystring [i] == ' ':
        newstring = newstring + mystring[i+1].upper()
print (newstring)
```

I am getting double letters. Here is the output -

```
Quick Bbrown Ffox, Jjumps Oover Tthe Llazy Ddog!
```

Comment: Your teacher would do well to remember that iterating over indices using `for i in range(len(container))` is frowned upon in python. Instead use `for element in container` to get the elements directly

Comment: ^^^ `enumerate` is preferable in situations where you also need the index, but iterating by element is so Pythonic.

Comment: You're getting doubled letters because when the current character is a space, you "look ahead" in the string to get the next letter as uppercase.  And then on the next loop iteration you get that letter _again_, in its normal lowercase form, because it is now the current letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! To debug the program it's often good to take the simple input and go line by line, drawing what is happening on some sheet of paper.

Here when your `i == 6` `mystring[i]` points to space. Condition is fulfilled, `nestring` becomes `"Quick" + "b".upper()`, great! But now `i==7` and you add `newstring` (which is Quick B) `mystring[i]` which is **b**.

To fix it you could e.g. check if previous character is a space:

```
for i in range (1,len(mystring)):
    if mystring [i-1] == ' ':
        newstring = newstring + mystring[i].upper()
    else:
        newstring = newstring + mystring[i]
```

And as a bonus, one liner for that.

```
" ".join(word.capitalize() for word in mystring.split(" "))
```

Comment: Hi Kosciej16, I see. Thank you very much for pointing that out and for showing me what the correct logic as well as another way to tackle the problem. I ran the code you provided and it worked. Thanks again very much!

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over indices using `for i in range(len(container))` is frowned upon in python. Instead use `for element in container` to get the elements directly. If you need the index, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the element *and* index.

As for your question: one approach would be to create a variable that remembers if your previous character was a space. If it was, make the current letter uppercase. If not, append it to the new string as-is.

Another point to remember is that when you append to a string repeatedly in a loop, e.g.: `str1 = str1 + new_character` python needs to copy *all* characters from the old string, plus your new character, to the new string every time this operation is performed. It is more efficient to append all your characters to a *list*, and use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join all elements of that list in one shot *after* your iterations are done.

```
mystring = 'quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog!'

result = []

uppercase_next = True # Since you want to uppercase the first character, we default this to True

for char in mystring:
    if uppercase_next:
        result.append(char.upper())
    else:
        result.append(char)

    uppercase_next = (char == " ")  # char == " " figures out if the character is a space, 
                                    # Then we assign the result to the variable uppercase_next
     
newstring = "".join(result)   
print(newstring)
```

Comment: Hi Pranav, got it! Thank you very much for the feedback. I also tested the code that you provided. It worked very well! Thanks again very much!